# Default Customizer Code

Tags: theme-customizer, customization

To create a new CUSTOM section in my Customizer I do this...

```
$wp_customize->add_section('logo_section_one',
array(
    'title' => __('Upload a Logo', 'mb' ),
    'description' => __('Use an image for your Logo', 'mb'),
    'priority' => 35,
    'panel'  => 'main_panel',
    ));
```

How do I add a DEFAULT section like Title and Tagline to the section that I want? I would preferably like to move the Title and Tagline (not have it display twice) to the section of my choosing. I have tried many different combinations of code but nothing works and the codex is extremely vague about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Default WordPress sections,into Customization API, are located in `wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php` file from line 912.

You can add any control,settings or section via your customization file, so you don't need hack WP Core Files.